# Can't run script in VScode (module error)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, module, pip, modulenotfounderror

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

What I tried: Added path to sysdm.cpl Ran multiple commands in terminal in VScode, like creating a venv and path changing.

Note:
Selenium is installed and can be found if I run pip --install selenium, yet it still throws an error when I run script in VScode

I have no clue how to run modules and want to start coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because multiple versions of python exist on your machine, and the environment where you successfully installed the `selenium` package is not the same python version as the environment you are using.

**Solution:**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> open command palette
2. search select `Python:Select Interpreter`
   [image]
3. Choose the correct interpreter
   [image]

***What is the correct interpreter?***

- Select the python environment where the `selenium` package has been successfully installed
- Select the python version you want to use, then create a new terminal to activate the environment, and finally install the `selenium` package for this environment in the new terminal

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not installed `selenium` for the same python interpreter that is running your script. In your script, put these two lines at the very top:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Then run this script like you normally would. This should print the path to the interpreter that is running your script, I'll assume it is `/path/to/python`

Now try running

```
/path/to/python -m pip install selenium
```

in your terminal. This should install `selenium` specifically for the python version that sits at `/path/to/python`

Comment: Hi FlyingTeller, thx for reply. CMD Log:

`PS C:\Users\Mr Golden\Desktop\Python> & "C:/Users/Mr Golden/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/Mr Golden/Desktop/Python/import sys.py"

C:\Users\Mr Golden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe

PS C:\Users\Mr Golden\Desktop\Python> /path/to/python -m pip install selenium
/path/to/python: The term '/path/to/python' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: You need to replace `/path/to/python` with your actual python path, so run `C:\Users\Mr Golden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install selenium`

Comment: Just ran `C:\Users\Mr Golden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install selenium` and this is my CMD log: `C:\Users\Mr: The term 'C:\Users\Mr' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: Sorry, need to put it in quotes of course `"C:\Users\Mr Golden\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" -m pip install selenium` (because there is a space in the path)