# Unable to import pygame even though it should be installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So I'm trying to install pygame using pip and then I'm trying to import pygame(using vscode by the way) but when I try to import it I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Doing python --version in the vscode terminal outputs that my python version is `Python 3.10.6` and when I do pip list it does show that pygame     2.1.2 is indeed installed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does it say ModuleNotFoundError from pip or when you import it in the code?

Comment: you may have common problem with two Pythons installed. You installed module in one Python but VSCode may run code with other Python. Run in VSCode `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python/exe` and use it to install module `/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install pygame`

Comment: check `pip --version` and see if it shows at the end `Python 3.10.6`. If it show different version then this `pip` installs modules for other version - but different versions don't share modules. You may also check if you have `pip3` or `pip3.10`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't run script in VScode (module error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372855/cant-run-script-in-vscode-module-error)

Comment: Nope that did not answer it @JialeDu and it's when I try to import it. I did pip3 --version because pip --version didn't work and it says (python 3.10) at the end, is that okay? it doesn't say 3.10.6 or 3.10.7

Comment: I printed sys.executable and got /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10 but none of the commands you said worked so I'm really not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a module for a specific python version:
`python3.10.6 -m pip install pygame`

But this command will probably throw an error, because pygame doesn't support python versions above 3.9.5 yet, so you have to use an older version or wait for a the next pygame release.